# Is there a way to specify a (sematic) document version with dublin core or the like?

Tags: metadata, ontology, dublin-core

I would like to add a semantic version to a document, which is an interface specification, using meta-data.

My preference would be  to not have something proprietary, but standards based, e.g. using [Dublin Core](https://www.dublincore.org/).

I already used the text search to find something in the vocabularies defined there and found two things:

- [hasVersion](https://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dcmi-terms/terms/hasVersion/)
- [isVersionOf](https://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dcmi-terms/#http://purl.org/dc/terms/isVersionOf)

However, both are meant to be used for "non-literal" values and reference another resource.

Frankly I did not fully understand in which way they shall be used.

Is there anything available for my use-case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dublin Core terms [`dcterms:hasVersion`](https://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dcmi-terms/#http://purl.org/dc/terms/hasVersion)/[`dcterms:isVersionOf`](https://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dcmi-terms/#http://purl.org/dc/terms/isVersionOf) are meant to link the versioned documents to each other, e.g.:

```
</documentation/v2/install> dcterms:isVersionOf </documentation/v1/install> .
```

To provide the version literal of a document, you could use the Schema.org property [`schema:version`](https://schema.org/version):

```
</documentation/v2/install> schema:version "2" .
```

If the document is an ontology: [`owl:versionInfo`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-owl-ref-20040210/#versionInfo-def)